# Mysql simple query hangs up under random circumstances

Tags: mysql

I'm using  MySQL Server 5.7.21 under Centos 7. I have two tables, structure below. And sometimes (not always), simple query like:

```
UPDATE `Main` SET `Cat`=0 WHERE `Cat` NOT IN (SELECT `Uin` FROM `Cat1`)
```

Hangs up for minutes. This situation does not depend on the number of rows in tables and other external factors. Tell me, what could be the problem?

```
CREATE TABLE `Main` (
  `Code` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
  `Nt` varchar(250) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `Ss` decimal(10,2) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0.00',
  `Nac` decimal(10,2) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0.00',
  `Price` decimal(10,2) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0.00',
  `Ei` int(2) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `Quant` decimal(10,3) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0.000',
  `Dateadded` datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `Sh` int(5) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `Post` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `Crit` decimal(10,3) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0.000',
  `Cat` int(5) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `Noskid` int(2) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `C2` int(2) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `Dopinf` int(2) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `Incloud` int(2) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0'
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

ALTER TABLE `Main`
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (`Code`),
  ADD KEY `Crit` (`Crit`),
  ADD KEY `Ei` (`Ei`),
  ADD KEY `Nac` (`Nac`),
  ADD KEY `Post` (`Post`),
  ADD KEY `Quant` (`Quant`);
COMMIT;


CREATE TABLE `Cat1` (
  `Uin` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `Cat1` varchar(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `Level` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `Puin` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0'
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

ALTER TABLE `Cat1`
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (`Uin`),
  ADD UNIQUE KEY `ind_UNIQUE` (`Uin`),
  ADD UNIQUE KEY `idx_name` (`Cat1`);
```

Comment: 'what could be the problem' - something else has lock, out of space, you claim volume is not an issue but I would be suspicious of in/not in why not use not exists? Is the update run raw / part of a trigger /part of an event /part of a procedure?

Comment: the update runs raw, everything is ok with free disk space. The problem occurs randomly on 3 servers running about 4000 databases with a similar structure. All other queries (some of them much more complex) run without problems.